# Integrating pure JQuery to CakePHP

Tags: jquery, cakephp-2.7

I am some months old cakephp, and I've been working on some web app using cakephp 2.7.3. So far am doing okay but I need to integrate jquery into the app for some functionalities. I've spent weeks googling on and trying various ways to add and make jquery work in my app to avail. Kindly assist.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I asked how to set up jquery in cakephp. I already got a working solution and thanks for your interest, I'd  appreciate any other suggestion though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this line to your View/Layouts/default.ctp

```
echo $this->Html->script('Url to your jQuery file');
```

And then youn can use jQuery in every view file like this:

```
<script>

   $(document).ready(function(){
      // Your code goes here
   });

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, Do you just put in the jquery filename as long as it is in webroot/js or do you have to specify the URL again?

Comment: Yes you just place the jquery file in webroot/js and thats it. You also don't need the file extension: echo $this->Html->script('jquery');

Comment: That worked like a charm. Thanks a lot. Sorry I couldn't respond in time